# Auto add nodes on save to a queue using entityqueue

Tags: 8, queue

I am using [entity queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue) module, Created a queue with a name *ABC*.

I want to add nodes automatically to this queue for a specific content type while creating new nodes.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try [Auto Entityqueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entityqueue) module to Automatically add entities to entityqueues.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom rule  which calls a function like

```
/**
* Add a node to a subqueue
*/
function abc_queue_add_node_to_entityqueue($subqueue, $node){
  $existing_nodes = abc_entity_queue_get_subqeueue_nodes($subqueue);
  if (!in_array($node->nid, $existing_nodes)) {
    $subqueue->eq_node[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array('target_id' => $node->nid);
    entityqueue_subqueue_save($subqueue);
  }
}
```